# how to reinit owl carousel custom json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel custom JSON in my application (here is the [link](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/customJson.html)). I need to use this method for three buttons in one page. Initial load is working really fine. But after initial load data not changing.

I checked it is not calling the customDataSuccess function even. How can I reinitialize this..?

Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath : 'http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/json/customData.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
  });
 
  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    for(var i in data["items"]){
       
       var img = data["items"][i].img;
       var alt = data["items"][i].alt;
 
       content += "<img src=\"" +img+ "\" alt=\"" +alt+ "\">"
    }
    $("#owl-demo").html(content);
  }
 
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item{
  background: #a1def8;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel"></div>
```

First time it is loading fine but after that it is not changing the owl carousel items. How can I reinitialize the owl carousel..?

Comment: I believe that json from third party URL is not loading. That's the only issue. Have you tried it in your application.

Comment: @Manish Yes I tried and first time it is loading perfect. From second time it is not calling the customDataSuccess function. That is the only issue.

Comment: Can you please call `$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath : 'http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/json/customData.json',
    jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
  });` again after  `$("#owl-demo").html(content);`

Comment: @Manish I solved it in another way. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Great !! Enjoy working ... :)